# How to convert 220 VDC to 24 VDC

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, high-voltage

I’m working on a project where I need to build a converter/power supply for converting 220 VDC to 24 VDC.

Yes, its 220 VDC not AC.

This convertor will be mounted on a locomotive type vehicle designed in 1960 but still in use. The vehicle has only one power option i.e. 220 VDC. We need to make 24VDC out of this for connecting surveillance camera, fan etc. Current required is not more than 10 Amps.

I tried searching on google, found converters that goes up to max 90 VDC i.e 90 to 24 VDC anything beyond that is not available.

What type of converter can I use for this voltage conversion?

Comment: How much variation can you expect in the input voltage?  Does it get spikes or dips when other equipment is switched on or off?

Comment: The ratio is a bit extreme for buck, the high voltage suggests that a non-isolated solution could be a liability as well, so best go for isolated transformer coupled. You may well find a universal input (110VAC-240VAC) brick will 'just work' on 220VDC, if it has a bridge rectifier input, which most do.

Comment: If you are looking for off the shelf options, https://www.simplypowersupply.com/DC-DC-Converter/220V-input-24v-output/default.aspx

Comment: I second what @Neil_UK says.  If you select a universal input 110-240V switching power supply as opposed to a dual input (typically 110-115 and  220-240) that uses the expected input rectification it should work out the box.  You may need to replace the fuse with a slow-blo type due to inrush current but selecting another specimen may work just fine. Niteesh Shanbog has also indicated a formally compatible though perhaps a little more expensive solution.

Comment: You may be able to design a 'buck-converter' for this but I would be designing a ['Forward Converter'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_converter).  Unless you know what you are doing though *Buy Something*. Most universal input switch mode power supplies will 'just work' as the first thing they do is rectify the AC to produce DC as pointed out by @Neil_UK.  Check with the manufacturer.

Comment: Most universal-input supplies should just work, but you may wish to add an external fuse as the internal one won't likely be adequate for DC.

Comment: well thank you all for your valuable comment. as advised by @Neil_UK . I will use SMPS circuit after rectifier for making a test board. I will also order an off the Shelf ABB PS to compare performance with test board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a general industrial power supply. Here is an example from ABB (90-300 V DC input, 24 V DC, 10 A output): [CP-C.1 24/10.0](https://search-ext.abb.com/library/Download.aspx?DocumentID=2CDC114100D0201&LanguageCode=en&DocumentPartId=&Action=Launch)

Another one from Phoenix Contact, certified for EN 50155 (rolling stock applications): [QUINT-PS/1AC/24DC/10/CO](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us/?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=2320911&library=usen)

Comment: This could be a nice option for an immediate start.I will check price from ABB. if it's not very expensive than i will definitely buy one. Thanks for suggestion.